# How to install a font for tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, fonts

I would like to use a chalk-like font on Tkinter. Is there one by default I can use, and if not, is there any way I can install one?

Thanks!

Comment: If you have installed this font on your PC, you could use it directly in tkinter.

Comment: how do you do this?

Comment: What? How to install font?

Comment: install the font, then in the 'font =' part, put in the right name, simple